# PD Controler on SciLab

Tags: simulation, pid-controller

[image]

I have been trying to simulate this system on SciLab using PID controler block, but I dont know if the given grafic is correct. Can someone please help?

This is the given graffic:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Is that correct?

This is how the system looks like on SciLab:
Consider J = 1.

Comment: why did you post the picture twice?

Comment: `Can someone please help?` is not a question about the problem